# Grafana - show metric grouped by day is shifted by 1 day

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am using Grafana v8.4.4 to visualize Docker container metrics. I would like to show amount of received traffic (upload), grouped by day. For this purpose, I am using `container_network_receive_bytes_total` metric provided by cAdvisor.

I am using the following Prometheus query:

```
sum(increase(container_network_receive_bytes_total[1d]))
```

Once visualized in Grafana, it looks like this (user selected `Last 7 days` at the top right of Grafana UI). I set `Min step` to `1d` (red rectangle in the photo):

[image]

[image]

I am writing this post on 6-Apr-2022. I noticed that the days in the graph are off by 1:

1. Today's data isn't displayed on the graph at all
2. The bar on the far right actually shows data from yesterday (5-Apr-2022), but its label still says 6-Apr-2022

I found a *"hack"* to show today's data as well. I had to set Time shift in query options to -1d (`0d+1d` in [Grafana syntax](https://community.grafana.com/t/how-to-set-a-negative-time-shift-to-see-the-selected-range-the-day-after/24472/2)):

[image]

[image]

Questions:

1. Why are dates off by 1 day? How can I fix this?
2. Why are there there 8 bars despite the fact that I selected `Last 7 days`?

Answer (score 0):

@Mark I use the below configuration.

[image: time shift]

which gives info as below:

[image: 1 week]

Comment: where do you see the location of these settings?

Answer (score 0):

It is solved for the recent versions of prometheus where you can give -ve offset in your query.
So in your case

```
sum(increase(container_network_receive_bytes_total[1d] offset -1d))
```

will give the desired result.

The hack you mentioned will affect all your queries in the panel.